# The use of graycomatrix offset parameter

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-extraction, glcm

I came across [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22187-glcm-texture-features) on how to call the function `graycomatrix`

```
>I = imread('circuit.tif'); 
>GLCM2 = graycomatrix(I,'Offset',[2 0;0 2]); 
>stats = GLCM_features1(GLCM2,0)
```

but I do not understand the effect of the second parameter in `graycomatrix`. I've read [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.in/help/toolbox/images/ref/graycomatrix.html) but the explanation is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 4):

The second and third parameters to `graycomatrix` are a combined name-value pair.  The value (`[2 0; 0 2]`) in this case is a matrix which determines the relative spacing (i.e. offset, the name of the parameter) of pixels which are examined in order to get the co-occurrence count of each value pair.

Each row in this `p-by-2` matrix defines a single relative position in `[row column]` format. The first row of the matrix is `[2 0]`.  This means that each pixel is compared to the pixel 2 rows down, 0 columns over (i.e. in the same column).  The second row `[0 2]` indicates that each pixel is **also** compared to the pixel 0 rows away (i.e. in the same row) and 2 columns over.

Thus, each pixel is compared against two of its neighbor pixels: the pixel 2 columns to the right, and the pixel 2 rows down.  The pairs formed by both of these relationships are used to increment the appropriate pixels in the output image.